Running dotnet Project.dll in Command Works, But Unable to Access URL
I created a new project and I'm trying to run the web app using PowerShell. The command runs successfully, but when I click on the URL, I encounter the following result. How can I resolve this issue?



There is the csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="dockerfile">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


First, make sure that there is a HomeController inside the project, and then check that there is an Index Action inside it.
By default, when you do not enter an address, the /Home/Index path will be automatically opened, and if there is no file, you will get a 404 error.

I'm only using an API, and I updated the post with my solution image. Is Docker checking specifically the HomeController? If I don't have any views, how can I use Docker?

You should use this address to get data: localhost:5000/WeatherForecast/GetWeatherForecast
